# Duplicate results when querying using SearchVector

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have an abstract model class called `PostType` with a few submodels derived from it.
The model looks like this:

```py
class PostType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Title'
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        default='',
        verbose_name='Description'
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=Tag,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Tags'
    )
    content = RichTextUploadingField(
        default='',
        verbose_name='Post Content'
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

It has a related Tag model that looks like this:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Name',
        unique=True
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Description',
        default=''
    )
```

In one of my views I am trying to query all of the subclasses, using a `SearchVector` and searching multiple fields:

```py
query = request.GET.get('s')

from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
get_qs_list = [model.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('title', 'description', 'content', 'tags__name')
).filter(search=query) for model in models.PostType.__subclasses__()]
```

Now, the search is returning all of the results that it should. However, for some reason it's returning duplicate results for *some* items.

The problem seems to go away if I remove `'tags__name'` from the `SearchVector`, but I don't understand why.

**What am I doing wrong, and why does it work if I don't search the related field?**

**EDIT:**

I just realized that I get a duplicate result for every `Tag` that the item is related to. So if the item has three tags, I will get three copies of the item in the search result. I still don't understand why this happens though, and I'm grateful for any advice!

Comment: Did you distinct the queryset?

Comment: @Blackdoor Thank you very much for your advice! I did not know I had to distinct a queryset when querying related posts. It does seem to pose me with a another issue though, as it seems like I have to distinct by the same field that I order_by. But at least I can take a closer look at a solution using distinct now! Thank you.

Comment: @Azer I know this question is old, but maybe there is a chance that you remeber if, and, how you reslove this :D? I have a same problem now, 
if I add .distinct('id'),  it says that i have to distnict them by the same field that I order_by.

Comment: @bazzuk123 I had the same problem and the sonution from here https://github.com/bruvellu/cifonauta/issues/137#issuecomment-377959559 worked for me: `SearchVector(StringAgg('relatedmodel__fieldname', delimiter=' '))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the question is old, but I've been struggling today with a very similar issue and found a solution. If you look at the search vector definition:

```py
search = SearchVector(
    'title',
    'description',
    'content',
    'tags__name',
)
```

## Explanation

You might notice that while `title`, `description` and `content` are fields on your model `PostType`, the `tags__name` refers to a related model `Tag`. In this case the relation is not a one-to-one - there might be **multiple** tags related to a certain PostType. If the search results with more than one tag "matching" your search, then you will get exactly as many results and Django's `distinct()` won't help you (at least not in any way that I know of).

However, since you are using postgres, you can also take advantage of another feature that is [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg). It allows you to annotate your queryset with an aggregated value of all tags, and later use is as it was a field on the PostType:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

# 1. annotate with aggregated tag name values
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    tags_names=ArrayAgg(
        "tags__name",
        distinct=True,
    ),
)

# 2. use the annotation in the SearchVector
search = SearchVector(
    'title',
    'description',
    'content',
    'tags_names',  # <-- note: not `tags__name`
)
```

For each `PostType` there will be only one `tags_names` consisting of aggregated `tags__name` values now, so in other words - being a list of related tag names; which can now be used in `SearchVector` like any other field.

## Final solution

*Side note: apart from that, for better results you should also check if `search__icontains=query`.*

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import Q

query = request.GET.get('s')

get_qs_list = [
    model.objects.annotate(
        tags_names=ArrayAgg("tags__name", distinct=True),
        search=SearchVector(
            'title',
            'description',
            'content',
            'tags_names',
        ),
    ).filter(
        Q(search=query) | Q(search__icontains=query)
    ) for model in models.PostType.__subclasses__()
]
```

Comment: I no longer work on this project, so I can't easily try this out, but it does indeed seem like a great fix for the issue I had! Thank you very much!

Comment: This works when u remove quotes and use the variable instead of string i.e search=SearchVector(
            'title',
            'description',
            'content',
            tags_names,
        ),